# Django Forms: how to re-evaluate default variables for each instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form (as a sub-class of django.forms.Form) that has a ChoiceField (i.e. a `<select>` dropdown). The ChoiceField's default choice list is made up of database records, so it will change periodically. Right now the list only updates when I restart the server. How can I define the class so that the choices will re-evaluate with each new instance?

**Edit:** Sorry, I should have added this from the beginning. Here's a sample of the code:

```
class MonthInitializationForm(forms.Form):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # list containing datetime.date objects of the current month, and the following 11 months
    months = [utilities.add_months(now, i) for i in range(0, 13)]

    # generate list of choices in form ('12/2014', 'December 2014') from months list
    choices = []

    for month in months:

        # if this form hasn't already been submitted for this month
        if not utilities.is_initialized(date=month):
            choices.append((month.strftime('%m/%Y'), month.strftime('%B %Y')))

    month = forms.ChoiceField(choices=months_choices)
```

Basically, this form "initializes" a month. I only want months within the next 0-11 months that have not already been initialized to be shown as options. Since this isn't really an SQL query, I can't define this using a `queryset`, can I? So, how can I use forms.ChoiceField or forms.ModelChoiceField to make this work, so that the choices are being re-evaluated with every instance?

Comment: Please, show your code!

Comment: Sorry, I just added it. Hopefully that'll help clear things up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `__init__` function of form to do the required. Generate the list of choices from db and assign it to the field. Something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    list_of_choices = (
                    (obj.some_field1, obj.some_field2) for obj in SomeTable.objects.all()
                    )
    self.fields['field_name'].choices = list_of_choices
```

Answer (score 0):

For choice fields dynamically generated from a model or queryset, you should use a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), which is specifically designed for this use case and automatically refreshes its choice list on form instantation.